# Unexpected Output Shape of Conv2D in Encoder of Autoencoder

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

I'm encountering an issue with the output shape of the Conv2D layer within the encoder of my convolutional autoencoder using Keras. The encoder output shape is turning out to be unexpected, such as (None, 50, 28, 1) instead of the anticipated (None, 28, 28, 50).(using tf2.8)

Here's a simplified version of my code:

```
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
import numpy as np

def build_encoder(input_shape):
    encoder_input = Input(shape=input_shape)
    x = Conv2D(filters=50, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(encoder_input)
    x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same')(x)
    x = Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
    encoded = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same')(x)
    encoder = Model(encoder_input, encoded)
    return encoder

# ... other code ...

# Input image shape
input_shape = (28, 28, 1)

# Build the autoencoder
autoencoder, encoder, decoder = build_autoencoder(input_shape)
autoencoder.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy')
autoencoder.fit(train_dataset, train_dataset, epochs=10, batch_size=32, shuffle=True)
```

When I print the shapes during the encoding process, I see:

```
(None, 50, 28, 1)
(None, 50, 14, 1)
(None, 16, 14, 1)
(None, 16, 7, 1)
```

I was expecting the output shape to be (None, 28, 28, 50) after the first Conv2D layer. I'm using (28, 28, 1) images as input. Can someone help me understand why the filters parameter of the Conv2D layer seems to affect the output shape like this? How can I achieve the intended output shape of (None, 28, 28, 50)?

Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

```
_________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
 input_1 (InputLayer)        [(None, 28, 28, 1)]       0         
                                                                 
 conv2d (Conv2D)             (None, 50, 28, 1)         12650     
                                                                 
 max_pooling2d (MaxPooling2D  (None, 50, 14, 1)        0         
 )                                                               
                                                                 
 conv2d_1 (Conv2D)           (None, 16, 14, 1)         7216      
                                                                 
 max_pooling2d_1 (MaxPooling  (None, 16, 7, 1)         0         
 2D)                                                             
                                                                 
=================================================================
Total params: 19,866
Trainable params: 19,866
Non-trainable params: 0
```

Comment: It looks like the Conv2D uses channels first. How do you construct the rest of the models? And can you look if you have this file: `~/.keras/keras.json`? Reference: https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r2.8/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Conv2D#args under `data_format`, especially `It defaults to the image_data_format value found in your Keras config file at ~/.keras/keras.json. If you never set it, then it will be channels_last.`

Comment: Would you provide the encoder layers summary.

Comment: You're welcome for the suggestion, and your idea is correct. I have resolved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Hi welcome to the community.
May be below snippet will help.

```
def build_encoder(input_shape):
    # Define the input layer
    encoder_input = Input(shape=input_shape)
    
    # First convolutional layer with 50 filters
    x = Conv2D(filters=50, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(encoder_input)
    
    # Max pooling layer to reduce dimensions
    x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same')(x)
    
    # Second convolutional layer with 16 filters
    x = Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
    
    # Second max pooling layer
    encoded = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same')(x)
    
    # Define the encoder model
    encoder = Model(encoder_input, encoded)
    return encoder
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. I have tried copying the code you provided and printing the output shape after the first layer, but I still get (None, 50, 28, 1). I'm unsure about what could be causing this issue, and I've thoroughly checked my sample data, which has a shape of (1000, 28, 28, 1) where 1000 is the number of samples. I would like to ask if anyone could help me understand what might be causing this situation. Thank you!